# Finding decimal numbers in a string that starts with "+" or "-"

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

I would like to fetch some decimal numbers from a string which I receive from a remote service.

My issue is that I only want decimals in the string prefixed with either "+" or "-".

Here is my current solution:

```
string text = "+123.23 foo 456.34 bar -789.56";
List<string> decimals = Regex.Split(text, @"[^0-9\.]+").Where(
                             c => c != "." && c.Trim() != string.Empty).ToList();

foreach (var str in decimals)
{
    Console.WriteLine(str); 
}

// Output:
//           
// 123.23 
// 456.34
// 789.56
//
// Desired output:
//
// 123.23
// -789.56
```

Since I don't know regex well, I would like some help with a more suitable pattern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I switched from `Split`ting on non-numbers to `Match`ing numbers. This gets the results you want:

```
string text = "+123.23 foo 456.34 bar -789.56";
List<string> decimals = Regex.Matches(text, @"[+\-][0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?")
                          .Cast<Match>().Select(m => m.Value).ToList();

foreach (var str in decimals)
{
    Console.WriteLine(decimal.Parse(str));
}
```

Comment: I believe a dash/minus character `-` does not have to be escaped if this character is first or last in a list.

Comment: @Ωmega you're right, it works either way. I have a habit of escaping `-`s in `[]`s, because sometimes it is an issue (e.g. if you want to match `[a-]` and then decide to add a `5` to that, `[a-5]` is invalid, or worse: `[5-a]` is valid, but not what you might've expected). I'll leave it the way I had it.

Comment: Sure, it is a good habit. I've just added that comment to clear this (irrelevant) issue, so others will know. It may be a useful information for some users...

Answer (score 2):

try `(\+|\-)[0-9\.]+`

```
string strRegex = @"(\+|\-)[0-9\.]+";
Regex myRegex = new Regex(strRegex);
string strTargetString = @"+123.23 foo 456.34 bar -789.56";

foreach (Match myMatch in myRegex.Matches(strTargetString))
{
  if (myMatch.Success)
  {

  }
}
```